# Is a totally ordered set consisting of discrete point sets containing point p a well-ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, transfinite-recursion

I have encountered a fully ordered set and want to determine whether it is well ordered.
Each element B in this totally ordered set A is a set and includes point p, which means that the elements in A may show the following situation:[image]

- My current attempt:
  I want to verify that A is well-ordered, then I need to discuss the existence of a minimum element for any non-empty subset S.
  If there is a set B in S such that it contains only finite points, it can be easily verified $\bigcap _{B\in S} B\in S$ by proof by contradiction.
  But if the elements in S are at least listable point sets, I don't know how to describe it.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is $A$ and the ordering on $A$? Is $A$ just an arbitrary subset of some $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (for some set $X$) linearly ordered by set inclusion, and such that all elements of $A$ contain some fixed point $p \in X$? If that's all the conditions, then no, $A$ certainly doesn't have to be well-ordered by inclusion. Just take $A = \{[0, s): s > 0\} \subset \mathcal{P}([0, \infty))$, say.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I forgot to write the partial order relationship. This relationship is the inclusion relationship of the set.

Comment: The elements in A are sets, and these sets are scatter sets that contain at least p .

Comment: What do you mean by scatter sets? And in any case is the counterexample I provided not satisfying some of your conditions? If so, you should clarify what further conditions you are requiring.

Comment: What I mean by scatter point set is: for example, B is one of the sets, with 3 points in it. These points come from R^2, (u1, v1), (u2, v2), (u3, v3) but there is no need for a connection relationship between them and can be considered as some randomly selected points. P is one of the points and has been selected.

Comment: @David Gao Thank you for the counterexample, but I think the situation here is slightly different because when constructing set B, I can randomly select points on the R^2 plane, which does not necessarily form an interval.

Comment: I suspect that by "scatter set" you mean "a set that consists of isolated points" and by "listable" you mean "countable."  The point of the example provided by @DavidGao is that it's an example proving that your ordering need not be a well ordering.  If you want a counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$ that actually uses $2$-dimensional sets,  let $A$ be the set of all open balls (of all possible positive radii) centered at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $A$ need not be well ordered.  Let $A= \{B((0, 0), r) \mid r \in \Bbb R^+ \}$, where $B((0, 0), r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $(0, 0)$.  Then $A$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb R^+$, which is not well ordered.